# Built in way to configure HTTPS with certificate in kestrel server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

Novice here. Is there are built in way to configure HTTPS with certificate in the ASP.NET core application?
Here's what I tried.
First I set the url and the certificate details in the settings.json

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001"
        }
      },
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
          "Subject": "<subject; required>",
          "Store": "<certificate store; required>",
          "Location": "<location; defaults to CurrentUser>",
          "AllowInvalid": "<true or false; defaults to false>"
                }
                  }
              }
}
```

and then I use configuration manager to load the configuration

```
builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("settings.json", false, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

Whenver I try to trigger the API using postman, I get "Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established". The controller works fine without the Certificates.Defaults section in the settings.json file.

What am I missing?

Comment: TLS is performed before the HTTPS request is sent.  The server sends a certificate block which contains the names of certificates that can be used.  Than client looks up certificate names in the user stores to find a matching certificate name.  You code instead of using the default certificates is trying to specify a particular certificate in the server.  So the failure either means the server or client found the certificate.  If the server did not get an exception than the server found the certificate and the issue is in the client.

Comment: The client probably will not give any error in c# since TLS is performed by the OS and doesn't report an error back to the app.  The error could also mean the client doesn't support the encryption method in the certificate.  Older OS will not work with TLS 1.3 certificates.  But then I think the certificate would give an error when loaded on the client.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the `appsettings.Production.json` and it works very well (Net 6/7):

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": " ... "
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": " ... ",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": " (your_cert_file.pfx) ",
          "Password": " (password) "
        },
      }
    }
  },
```

The certificate file path is relative to the working folder.

Comment: Anything specific that I need to take care in Program.cs file apart from what's mentioned?

Comment: I don't see anything particular in the code.

Comment: what about the certificate generation? What did you use dotnet dev-cert or openssl tool?

Comment: good question. I'm not the person that manage it, but a colleague does. I know we're using a 3rd party product, but I don't know what.