# Kestrel ignores certificate configuration in code

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, kestrel-http-server

## Problem Statement

Kestrel should listen to `http://localhost:50008` and `https://localhost:50009`. The certificate should be loaded from an external source at startup (in this example it's just loaded from files). Unfortunately, it only works if loaded from `appsettings.json` (as described in [Built in way to configure HTTPS with certificate in kestrel server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76796770/built-in-way-to-configure-https-with-certificate-in-kestrel-server)) and not if configured in code (as described in [ASP.NET Core application setup production SSL certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62351899/asp-net-core-application-setup-production-ssl-certificate)).

## Experiments

### Setup

The certificate is issued by Letsencrypt (production, not staging) for `*.mydomain.xyz`. The A record for `www.mydomain.xyz` points to `127.0.0.1`.

### Experiment 1: Configure Kestrel in appsettings.json

`Program.cs`

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/", () => Results.Ok("hello"));
app.Run();
```

`appsettings.json`

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Debug"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://*:50009",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "C:\\Users\\myusername\\certs\\acme_certificate_pem.crt",
          "KeyPath": "C:\\Users\\myusername\\certs\\acme_certificate_private_key_pem.key"
        }
      },
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://*:50008"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`debug output`

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]     
      Now listening on: http://[::]:50008
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]                 
      Now listening on: https://[::]:50009
```

`curl` (browser also shows correct cert for *.mydomain.xyz)

```bash
$ curl http://www.mydomain.xyz:50008
"hello"
$ curl https://www.mydomain.xyz:50009
"hello"
```

### Experiment 2: Configure Kestrel in Program.cs

`Program.cs`

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var certPath = "C:\\Users\\myusername\\certs\\acme_certificate_pem.crt";
var keyPath = "C:\\Users\\myusername\\certs\\acme_certificate_private_key_pem.key";
var certificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(certPath, keyPath);

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
{
    serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 50008);
    serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 50009, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps(certificate);
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/", () => Results.Ok("hello"));
app.Run();
```

`appsettings.json`

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Debug"
    }
  }
}
```

`debug output`

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]        
      Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:50008
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]                 
      Now listening on: https://0.0.0.0:50009
```

`curl`

```bash
$ curl http://www.mydomain.xyz:50008
"hello"
$ curl https://www.mydomain.xyz:50009
curl: (35) schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
```

### Experiment 3: Configure Kestrel in Program.cs without Cert

`Program.cs`

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
{
    serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 50008);
    serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 50009, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps();
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/", () => Results.Ok("hello"));
app.Run();
```

`appsettings.json`

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Debug"
    }
  }
}
```

`debug output`

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]        
      Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:50008
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]                 
      Now listening on: https://0.0.0.0:50009
```

`curl` (uses development certificate, issued to localhost)

```bash
$ curl http://www.mydomain.xyz:50008
"hello"
$ curl https://www.mydomain.xyz::50009 -k
"hello"
$ curl https://www.mydomain.xyz::50009
curl: (60) schannel: SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - Der Zielprinzipalname ist falsch.
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Comment: I look at your description and it seems that we are still using VS2022 for debugging, then we should modify the [launchSettings.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHCMq.png) instead of appsettings.json.

Comment: Or you can publish the project to the folder, and double-click the .exe file, then test again.